Run python via startup script in a GCP VM
GCP experts!
I have a linux virtual machine set up on GCP. I would like to turn it on and off at a schedule, and when I turn it on, trigger a python script I have at the root.
When I do it via SSH, once I enter the VM I just create a virtual session by typing screen -r bot and then I type main.py in the screen to start the script.
Can you help me to create a startup script that performs the two steps above?
I referred to GCP's reference page but that didn't help me to know how to write the actual script. Chat GPT offered a few options but after a few different attempts nothing was ever running when I logged into the VM via SSH to check.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/linux#console

What did you try? The documentation is a great place to start, experiment things and it should work in the end. The trap is your startup script is ran as a root user, and all the "usual" user context, when you use SSH, is not loaded. Most of the time, using absolute path (even to run python main.py is a requirement. Side question: do you need special amount of CPU or GPU in your script?

You can follow these documents for scheduling a VM. Question is do you have any sleep period or any virtual session command executions in the python script ?

You can use the startup script option under the metadata section to make the GCP Virtual Machine execute the booting scripts. For your question to use the screen session, the below script might be helpful. Make changes for the path and version of Python you are using accordingly.
startup.sh
#!/bin/bash

# 1. Check if screen session "bot" exists
if ! screen -list | grep -q "bot"; then
  # If not, create a new detached screen session
  screen -dmS bot
fi

SCRIPT_PATH="/path_to_python_script" #Change the path here

# Detach the script from the current terminal

screen -dmS bot bash -c "python3 $SCRIPT_PATH"  #update the python command incase if your using different version

# Print a success message
echo "Python script '$SCRIPT_PATH' started in screen session 'bot'."

exit 0

You can use this script for startup in multiple ways as mentioned below official GCP reference documents :

Passing startup script directly

Passing startup script from a local file

Passing startup script from Google cloud storage


First option is highly recommended as it is quick and easy to follow. You can follow these documents for scheduling a VM to start and stop.

Did you have time to check my answer? Has it helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further.What should I do when someone answers my question?
